# not recover and convert the data in formatted way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the data like this in python and is of string type.

```
('single image encodings************', '[-0.0810571   0.07765304 -0.01207364 -0.07887193 -0.10862262  0.00894677\n  0.02332557 -0.13491267  0.17760251 -0.05169698  0.14168473 -0.02124487\n -0.18840104 -0.00166624 -0.04524321  0.05642941 -0.20851628 -0.11587431\n -0.06982738 -0.09224549  0.07435957  0.05051775 -0.00907151  0.06328857\n -0.21342427 -0.28789386 -0.16309851 -0.0865657   0.15885921 -0.1180099\n -0.02833412  0.05563367 -0.20987368 -0.08260232  0.01715455  0.03688456\n -0.0463421  -0.07057426  0.19063213  0.06713615 -0.15279283  0.05829819\n  0.08128895  0.29696086  0.22681116  0.09677196 -0.02023378 -0.0361901\n  0.09358779 -0.23957716  0.15015952  0.13825837  0.00492278  0.06615157\n  0.1174949  -0.17725426 -0.03603006  0.03409255 -0.1879885   0.03505005\n  0.04937597  0.00329883 -0.01896965 -0.00677846  0.0996637   0.10273074\n -0.03806393 -0.14637196  0.15648144 -0.23035409 -0.05747294  0.03025337\n -0.0691918  -0.11424079 -0.28547999  0.05400954  0.4612399   0.20551455\n -0.1205992   0.10039085 -0.02485273 -0.08657033  0.15424132  0.02397859\n -0.10445568  0.06970545 -0.08628456  0.10466914  0.15395048  0.03581595\n -0.06539053  0.2473422   0.02394313  0.01033761  0.12121034  0.07658306\n -0.15766957 -0.04047695 -0.17851622 -0.08721714  0.14192414  0.04055045\n  0.01483513  0.19600785 -0.14814621  0.20973045  0.02028378 -0.06801224\n -0.08009423 -0.02115281 -0.14955129  0.01807878  0.1297669  -0.2507216\n  0.11424468  0.11775573 -0.05532342  0.11031963  0.10643894 -0.02885438\n  0.03168463 -0.0032694  -0.15598211 -0.09769975  0.07611469 -0.02105711\n  0.09928153  0.03357534]\n')
```

how can I convert the above data in this way this is the dimensional array data.
type of this data is 'numpy.ndarray'
I want numpy.ndarray below data...

("my output is", [-0.0810571   0.07765304 -0.01207364 -0.07887193 -0.10862262  0.00894677
      0.02332557 -0.13491267  0.17760251 -0.05169698  0.14168473 -0.02124487
     -0.18840104 -0.00166624 -0.04524321  0.05642941 -0.20851628 -0.11587431
     -0.06982738 -0.09224549  0.07435957  0.05051775 -0.00907151  0.06328857
     -0.21342427 -0.28789386 -0.16309851 -0.0865657   0.15885921 -0.1180099
     -0.02833412  0.05563367 -0.20987368 -0.08260232  0.01715455  0.03688456
     -0.0463421  -0.07057426  0.19063213  0.06713615 -0.15279283  0.05829819
      0.08128895  0.29696086  0.22681116  0.09677196 -0.02023378 -0.0361901
      0.09358779 -0.23957716  0.15015952  0.13825837  0.00492278  0.06615157
      0.1174949  -0.17725426 -0.03603006  0.03409255 -0.1879885   0.03505005
      0.04937597  0.00329883 -0.01896965 -0.00677846  0.0996637   0.10273074
     -0.03806393 -0.14637196  0.15648144 -0.23035409 -0.05747294  0.03025337
     -0.0691918  -0.11424079 -0.28547999  0.05400954  0.4612399   0.20551455
     -0.1205992   0.10039085 -0.02485273 -0.08657033  0.15424132  0.02397859
     -0.10445568  0.06970545 -0.08628456  0.10466914  0.15395048  0.03581595
     -0.06539053  0.2473422   0.02394313  0.01033761  0.12121034  0.07658306
     -0.15766957 -0.04047695 -0.17851622 -0.08721714  0.14192414  0.04055045
      0.01483513  0.19600785 -0.14814621  0.20973045  0.02028378 -0.06801224
     -0.08009423 -0.02115281 -0.14955129  0.01807878  0.1297669  -0.2507216
      0.11424468  0.11775573 -0.05532342  0.11031963  0.10643894 -0.02885438
      0.03168463 -0.0032694  -0.15598211 -0.09769975  0.07611469 -0.02105711
      0.09928153  0.03357534])

thanks in advance

Comment: Wow, this question is very clear and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace all brackets and newline & split by space.

```
#from numpy import array
k = ('single image encodings************', '[-0.0810571   0.07765304 -0.01207364 -0.07887193 -0.10862262  0.00894677\n  0.02332557 -0.13491267  0.17760251 -0.05169698  0.14168473 -0.02124487\n -0.18840104 -0.00166624 -0.04524321  0.05642941 -0.20851628 -0.11587431\n -0.06982738 -0.09224549  0.07435957  0.05051775 -0.00907151  0.06328857\n -0.21342427 -0.28789386 -0.16309851 -0.0865657   0.15885921 -0.1180099\n -0.02833412  0.05563367 -0.20987368 -0.08260232  0.01715455  0.03688456\n -0.0463421  -0.07057426  0.19063213  0.06713615 -0.15279283  0.05829819\n  0.08128895  0.29696086  0.22681116  0.09677196 -0.02023378 -0.0361901\n  0.09358779 -0.23957716  0.15015952  0.13825837  0.00492278  0.06615157\n  0.1174949  -0.17725426 -0.03603006  0.03409255 -0.1879885   0.03505005\n  0.04937597  0.00329883 -0.01896965 -0.00677846  0.0996637   0.10273074\n -0.03806393 -0.14637196  0.15648144 -0.23035409 -0.05747294  0.03025337\n -0.0691918  -0.11424079 -0.28547999  0.05400954  0.4612399   0.20551455\n -0.1205992   0.10039085 -0.02485273 -0.08657033  0.15424132  0.02397859\n -0.10445568  0.06970545 -0.08628456  0.10466914  0.15395048  0.03581595\n -0.06539053  0.2473422   0.02394313  0.01033761  0.12121034  0.07658306\n -0.15766957 -0.04047695 -0.17851622 -0.08721714  0.14192414  0.04055045\n  0.01483513  0.19600785 -0.14814621  0.20973045  0.02028378 -0.06801224\n -0.08009423 -0.02115281 -0.14955129  0.01807878  0.1297669  -0.2507216\n  0.11424468  0.11775573 -0.05532342  0.11031963  0.10643894 -0.02885438\n  0.03168463 -0.0032694  -0.15598211 -0.09769975  0.07611469 -0.02105711\n  0.09928153  0.03357534]\n')
a = k[1]

a = a.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("\n", "")
print [a]
```

Result:

```
['-0.0810571   0.07765304 -0.01207364 -0.07887193 -0.10862262  0.00894677  0.02332557 -0.13491267  0.17760251 -0.05169698  0.14168473 -0.02124487 -0.18840104 -0.00166624 -0.04524321  0.05642941 -0.20851628 -0.11587431 -0.06982738 -0.09224549  0.07435957  0.05051775 -0.00907151  0.06328857 -0.21342427 -0.28789386 -0.16309851 -0.0865657   0.15885921 -0.1180099 -0.02833412  0.05563367 -0.20987368 -0.08260232  0.01715455  0.03688456 -0.0463421  -0.07057426  0.19063213  0.06713615 -0.15279283  0.05829819  0.08128895  0.29696086  0.22681116  0.09677196 -0.02023378 -0.0361901  0.09358779 -0.23957716  0.15015952  0.13825837  0.00492278  0.06615157  0.1174949  -0.17725426 -0.03603006  0.03409255 -0.1879885   0.03505005  0.04937597  0.00329883 -0.01896965 -0.00677846  0.0996637   0.10273074 -0.03806393 -0.14637196  0.15648144 -0.23035409 -0.05747294  0.03025337 -0.0691918  -0.11424079 -0.28547999  0.05400954  0.4612399   0.20551455 -0.1205992   0.10039085 -0.02485273 -0.08657033  0.15424132  0.02397859 -0.10445568  0.06970545 -0.08628456  0.10466914  0.15395048  0.03581595 -0.06539053  0.2473422   0.02394313  0.01033761  0.12121034  0.07658306 -0.15766957 -0.04047695 -0.17851622 -0.08721714  0.14192414  0.04055045  0.01483513  0.19600785 -0.14814621  0.20973045  0.02028378 -0.06801224 -0.08009423 -0.02115281 -0.14955129  0.01807878  0.1297669  -0.2507216  0.11424468  0.11775573 -0.05532342  0.11031963  0.10643894 -0.02885438  0.03168463 -0.0032694  -0.15598211 -0.09769975  0.07611469 -0.02105711  0.09928153  0.03357534']
```

Comment: when i print the a like print("my out is",a) it not shows the correct output becoz of split

Comment: for the output when i print a  it shows the correct output but when i print("my output is",a) the output is not in formatted ways so further i cant process this encosding..

Comment: I just updated the print statement. Is this how you want?

Comment: no, i need output without commas seperated in plan values as shown above in result.

Comment: But that is not an array it is a string?

Comment: yes i want to remove the string only..inside the array data i want as it is data in the output i shown above i want that type of result

Comment: Edited solution. is that what you are expecting?

Comment: i want that type of output that i mention in my dout above in an array between two values i dont want commas seperated values

Comment: no sir i dont want the commas between two values in an array and the value are also in string i.e '0.1254' i want only 0.1254 ....the output thats u shown is in one line i want that output in dimentionals..